# Preg_replace multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't have access to functions.php or header.php in my WordPress installation.

I need to replace some meta data in the head for some pages.

I have tried this:

```
//get header
ob_start();
get_header();
$header_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo preg_replace('/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*)">/i','<meta property="og:image" content="image path" />', $header_content);
echo preg_replace('/<meta property="og:url" content="(.*)">/i','<meta property="og:image" content="url path" />', $header_content);
```

But only the first line (og:image) gets replaced.

I have also tried doing the preg_replace as an array and the same issue happens.

Can I replace multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange that you'd have access to create an arbitrary .PHP file while not having access to the `functions.php` or `header.php` files… But I digress:

Take a look at the documentation for [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), by default it replaces an unlimited number of times, so it should be matching every instance that's available to it at the time it's called.

I'd wager that your code is executing before all of the content is built into the header. You'd be better off finding out what hooks are being used to add that code to your header, and writing a function that hooks into the last hook at a lower priority.

As a quick fix though, especially since it sounds like you don't necessarily have *full* control of the site, would be to use an output buffer on the [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook. If there's ever anything baked into an old template/plugin or something along those lines that I can't filter/remove with hooks for some reason (and the budget doesn't allow for a rebuild, lol), this is generally what I do:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so62564906_global_find_replace', 99 );
function so62564906_global_find_replace(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        /**
         * $buffer should contain all your markup for the page.
         * Be VERY careful as to what you modify.
         */

        $buffer = preg_replace( '/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*)">/i', '<meta property="og:image" content="image path" />', $buffer );
        $buffer = preg_replace( '/<meta property="og:url" content="(.*)">/i', '<meta property="og:image" content="url path" />', $buffer );

        return $buffer;
    });
}
```

If that doesn't work, then perhaps your code *is* working, and the different instances of your meta tags aren't being matched in `preg_replace` because of typos, different orders of the attributes, different amount of spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used the tags here

```
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$title = "My New Title";
$og_image = "Full Path to the image";

$buffer = preg_replace('/(<title>)(.*?)(<\/title>)/i', '$1' . $title . '$3', $buffer);

$buffer = preg_replace('/<meta property="og:title" content="(.*?)(\")/i', '/<meta property="og:title" content="'.$title.'"' , $buffer);

$buffer = preg_replace('/<meta property="og:image" content="(.*?)(\")/i', '/<meta property="og:image" content="'.$og_image.'"' , $buffer);



echo $buffer;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.